# How to put the selected number into next edittext?

Tags: android, eclipse

Good day!

i am quite new in programming and i am trying to make a simple android app. i have here 2 edittext and 2 buttons inside my activity and what i want them to do is get the number of prefered contacts to text and the 1st edittext and 1st button succeeded but my problem is the button 2 also put the number on the 1st edittext that is supposed to put in 2nd edittext any idea?

this is my code..

```
public class SA extends Activity {

EditText con1;
EditText con2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_s);

    con1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnum1);
    con2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnum2);


    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectContact1)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
        }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectContact2)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v2) {
            // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            intent2.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);                
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,},
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    showSelectedNumber(number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult2(int requestCode2, int resultCode2, Intent data2) {
    if (data2 != null) {
        Uri uri2 = data2.getData();

        if (uri2 != null) {
            Cursor c2 = null;
            try {
                c2 = getContentResolver().query(uri2, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,},
                        null, null, null);

                if (c2 != null && c2.moveToNext()) {
                    String number2 = c2.getString(0);
                    showSelectedNumber(number2);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c2 != null) {
                    c2.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(String number) {
    con1.setText(number);
}
public void showSelectedNumber2(String number2) {
    con2.setText(number2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `onActivityResult2()` because `startActivityForResult()` gives you result back in `onActivityResult()` method.

So now your question would be, how you can manage different requests? Well, that you can do by passing different request code while calling startActivityForResult().

For example:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  // first request
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);  // second request
// you can pass any random number as a request code
```

Now you just need to perform the operations according to the request code received back in `onActivityResult()` method.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {

      if(requestCode == 1) {
            ...
            ...
      } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            ...
            ...
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes move it to the requestCode == 2 logic given above!

Comment: @PareshMayani when i tried to do the requestCode == 2 it says it is a Dead Code.

Comment: Dude you have pass requestCode 2 while starting activity for the second button!